# How to select and copy specific columns in a table that's been filtered with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've created a tool that allows the user to filter a table. I'd like to create a button that allows them to select the results and copy it to their clipboard. But I only want the button to select specific columns (for example, there's 12 columns and I only want columns 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, & 7 to be selected and copied to the clipboard).

I have only been able to find ways to select the full table and to copy it but nothing about selecting and copying specific columns of the table.

In my sample code below, I'd like to be able to sort the third column (either US or CA) and then be able to select column 0 and 1 to be copied.

```
<input type="button" value="Copy table to clipboard" onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById('myTable') );">

<select id="myList" onchange="myFunction()" class='form-control'>
<option label="Select State"></option>
<option>US</option>
<option>CA</option>
</select>

<table class="w3-table-all w3-margin-top" id="myTable">
<tr>
  <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Option 1</th>
  <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Option 2</th>
  <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Option 3</th>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>ABC</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>US</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>DEF</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>US</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>GHI</td>
  <td>1684</td>
  <td>CA</td>

</tr>
</table>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
   var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
   input = document.getElementById("myList");
   filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   table = document.getElementById("myTable");
   tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
   for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
     td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
     if (td) {
       txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
       if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         tr[i].style.display = "";
       } else {
         tr[i].style.display = "none";
       }
     }
   }
 }
     function selectElementContents(el) {
     var body = document.body,
       range, sel;
     if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
       range = document.createRange();
       sel = window.getSelection();
       sel.removeAllRanges();
       try {
         range.selectNodeContents(el);
         sel.addRange(range);
       } catch (e) {
         range.selectNode(el);
         sel.addRange(range);
       }
     } else if (body.createTextRange) {
       range = body.createTextRange();
       range.moveToElementText(el);
       range.select();
     }
     document.execCommand("Copy");
     window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
     document.selection.empty();

   }
</script>
```

Also have a JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/SMErickson7/tjqhngrs/4/

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: Please post your try

Comment: I updated it with an example.